# Getting Error when create app folder in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, directory

I got problem with creating folder for `PhotoLibrary`.
Does anyone know what is wrong there?

```swift
var albumPlaceholder:PHObjectPlaceholder!

//create the folder
NSLog("\nFolder \"%@\" does not exist\nCreating now...", albumName)
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
    let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle(albumName)
    albumPlaceholder = request.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection

}, completionHandler: { (success: Bool, error: NSError!) in
    NSLog("Creation of folder -> %@", (success ? "Success" : "Error!"))
    self.albumFound = (success ? true : false)
    if success {
        let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers([albumPlaceholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)
        self.assetCollection = collection?.firstObject as PHAssetCollection
    }
})
```

This code all the time prints `Error!` on console. Thanks in advance!

[Update]
My error is like this.

`Creation of folder -> Error! ViewWillAppear Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2047 "Photos Access not allowed (authorization status 0)" UserInfo=0x7fd1fb664cc0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Photos Access not allowed (authorization status 0)}`

Comment: Instead of logging your own "Error!" string, log the error itself. What does it actually say?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to declare the placeholder outside the `performChanges` block. It is useful only within the block. And `self.albumFound = (success ? true:false)` is sort of a waste; just set `self.albumFound` to `success`, eh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have permission to access Photo Library.
You need to request it first. So use the following code for that:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization{ status in
   switch status {
      case .authorized:
         // Permission Granted
         print("Write your code here")
      case .denied:
         // Permission Denied
         print("User denied")
      default:
         print("Restricted")
   }
}
```

For more info refer : [requestAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHPhotoLibrary/requestAuthorization:)

Comment: Thank you very much it helepd! I thought that prompt that was appearing on screan was handing this. But it wasn't.

Comment: @Rafik991: Happy to know that it worked for you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

The NSError tells you what the problem is:

> Photos Access not allowed (authorization status 0)

The problem is that you have failed to obtain authorization from the user to use the photos library.

For more info, see the docs on [`requestAuthorization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHPhotoLibrary/requestAuthorization:)

Comment: It is strange, because I am clicking OK on my prompt screan.

Comment: Authorization is asynchronous, so you have to get permission at some _earlier_ time. You can't do it as part of _this_ code.